# Arduino board consumption benchmark

Tags: power-supply, arduino, servo, power-consumption, comparison

I know consumption depend of the type of application, but I would like to know if a comparison of average consumption exist between arduino and similar boards (Teeny/Dfrduino...).

The board I am looking will control small servos, so the resolution and clock speed is not a constraint.
I didn't find much information about it during my research, so if you know where to start in order to find the answer I would be happy.

Thank you for your help. (sorry for my english)

Comment: probably not a comparison but you might be able to find it for each board. You can certainly find it for each microcontroller chip.

Comment: Thank you Sir for your help